# MongoDB historical data storage - best practice?

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

Assuming I have an user who has an ID and I want to store a historical record (document) on this user every day, what is better:

- create a new document for each record and search for the user id; or
- keep updating and embedding that data into one single user document which keeps growing over time?

Mostly I want to retrieve only the current document for the user but all records should be accessible at any time without a super long search/query.

Comment: GivEn that most of the time you want just the current document you should be more interested in being able to retrieve *that* "without a super long search/query"

Comment: yes that's what I was thinking but just wanted to make sure that this is in fact the right approach (also thanks for editing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of variables that can affect such a decision. One big document seems most obvious provided it doesn't grow to unpractically large or even disallowed sizes (mind you, a document can be at most 16MB in size).

Using document per entry is also perfectly viable and provided you create the appropriate indexes should not result in slow queries.

Answer (score 4):

There is a limit to how big a document can be. It's (as of v1.8) 16 MB. So you can simply run out of room if you update & embed. Also, mongo allocates document space based on average document size in a collection. If you keep adjusting/resizing this might have negative performance implications.

I think it's much safer to create new documents for each record and if/when you want to collate that data, you do it in a map/reduce job.

Comment: The size limit is 16MB as of 1.8 ;)

Comment: thank you for your answer. As both replies are of equal quality (IMHO) I will mark Remons one as correct solely because as of now you have one more upvote and he also has less points, hope you dont mind. Your answer is still much appreciated.